# What's the purpose of n_labels in make_multilabel_classification?

Tags: scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_classes=3, n_labels=2, random_state=1)
```

While the n_labels=2, why there are values of [1,1,1] in y? Doesn't this mean there are 3 labels for certain examples?  According to the documentation of n_labels:

```
n_labels : int, optional (default=2)
The average number of labels per instance. More precisely, the number
        of labels per sample is drawn from a Poisson distribution with
        ``n_labels`` as its expected value, but samples are bounded
```

So n_labels=2 doesn't mean the max number of predicted labels is 2, but on average is 2. In this case, why should I specify this parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could still be interested in varying the average number of labels.
For example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=5, n_features=10,
                                      n_classes=20, n_labels=2, random_state=1)
print(y)
# [[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]]

X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=5, n_features=10,
                                      n_classes=20, n_labels=15, random_state=1)
print(y)
# [[1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
#  [1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
#  [1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1]
#  [1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1]
#  [1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1]]
```